# .NET Core xml parser not accepting codepage Windows-1252

Tags: xml, .net-core, wix

I'm converting a WiX script from v3 to v4. I'm now using the .NET Core CLI. I got stuck on line 1 (of course) with WiX no longer accepting `Windows-1252`.

```
C:\Users\Mikey\OneDrive\Development Battambang>wix build -arch x64 MikeyPersonal.wxs
C:\Users\Mikey\OneDrive\Development Battambang\MikeyPersonal.wxs(1) : error WIX0104: Not a valid source file
; detail: System does not support 'windows-1252' encoding. Line 1, position 31.
```

Line 1 specifies

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
```

I'm on Windows 11 now. When I wrote the XML, I used vim and researched what the codepage was that I was saving. Maybe it's even specified in my `.vim` files. I don't think it has changed.

What shall I do?

Comment: Just load the file in your favorite code text editor, save it using `UTF-8`, and then switch to `encoding=utf-8` in your `.wix` file?

Comment: HTML is not XML.  You cannot parse HTML with XML parser.  Windows-1252 is HTML.  XML uses UTF-8.  Should be : <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

Comment: @marc_s Well I checked my .vimrc and it has been set to output UTF8 by default.  So yeah, your solution is correct.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, it's looking like I got the windows-1252 idea from HTML somewhere.  I've changed my WiX script (which is xml) to now use UTF8.  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggested comments, I've changed the script to use the UTF8 encoding, and have specified that accordingly in the xml header.